# regex matches wrong expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have 2 different strings like

```
abs1.qwerty.com:1234
```

and

```
abs11qwerty.com:1234
```

After using such regex **`"(?=" + name + ").*?:(\\d+)"`**, where name is a given string. I receive wrong match, because it assumes they are the same. What can be a solution to such problem?

Comment: 1) Format your code. 2) Provide example input and expected output. 3) Provide actual output.

Answer (score 2):

You need to regex escape `name` - this is classic **injection attack**.

If `name` has regex characters in it the engine will interpret them them as part of the pattern, for example

```
name = ".*"
```

will likely match all names, allowing an attacker to extract data from the system.

Use something like the following:

```
final String pattern = String.format("(?=%s).*?:(\\d+)", Pattern.quote(name))
```

---

In your example, if the pattern is `abs1.qwerty.com` the regex engine interprets this is:

- "abs1"- literal
- "." - any character, once
- "qwerty" - literal
- "." - any character, once
- "com" - literal

So the pattern happily matches "abs11qwerty.com".